# How to disable the previous dates from current date in calendar

Tags: android

I have created the custom calendar in grid view format.But the previous dates also enable in calendar view.How to disable the previous dates from current date in calendar.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

or if you have DatePickerDialog instance than get datepicker from that and set minimum date

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```